# CakePHP 3.6 dispatcher deprecated

Tags: cakephp

I have error on cakePHP 3.6 when I try run test with request. I tried go with this tutorial [http stack to an existing application](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/application.html#adding-the-new-http-stack-to-an-existing-application), but I had everything updated. I didn't update cakePHP. I started from 3.6. This error is in cakephp core. Someone have idea how to fix it? I don't even know where should I search error

> Dispatcher is deprecated. You should update your application to use
>   the Http\Server implementation instead. -
>   vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/LegacyRequestDispatcher.php,
>   line: 73  You can disable deprecation warnings by setting
>   `Error.errorLevel` to `E_ALL & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED` in your
>   config/app.php. in [vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Core/functions.php,
>   line 310]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [so many deprecated after updating 3.4.13 to 3.6 cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49877063/so-many-deprecated-after-updating-3-4-13-to-3-6-cakephp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you are calling `parent::setUp()` in your test case's `setUp()` method. Otherwise `IntegrationTestCase` won't use `MiddleWareDispatcher` and will fall back to deprecated `LegacyRequestDispatcher`.

(Look at `IntegrationTestCase::_makeDispatcher()` and `IntegrationTestCase::setUp()` for details on how `IntegrationTestCase` determines what dispatcher class to use.)

Comment: in my setUp() I have only $accessToken = $this->post('/api/user/token', $data); and it's everything what I wrote, because I got this error. It extends from IntegrationTestCase which is a default for the framework and when I debug it my test go to that path and execute return $dispatcher->dispatch($request, $response); but it's in vendor

Comment: There you go... Just add `parent::setUp();` as the first statement of your setUp() method and give it a try.